# Can I ask a reference letter from my Operating Systems professor while applying to Machine Learning programme?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, recommendation-letter

I am going to apply for a Computer Science master's programme in the field of Machine Learning or data science, but I asked a professor who taught me a different subject (Operating Systems) for a reference letter. Does it matter since these are two different subjects?

Comment: Can you clarify these acronyms? Specifically, what is OS?

Comment: @Florian possibly Operating Systems?

Comment: I don't think operating systems is a "different field" from machine learning; both are subfields of computer science.  A different _field_ would be something like mathematics or chemistry.  (Even with this interpretation, the short answer to the title question is "Yes".)

Comment: This sounds like [splitting hairs](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/split-hairs) to me. For 2 of the 4 graduate programs I applied to in Fall 1980, I used 4 references --- 2 in mathematics, 1 in physics, 1 in chemistry. (I got accepted to all 4 programs.)

Answer (score 4):

A good recommendation is one that highlights your potential as a researcher and your related technical and interpersonal skills. If the mentioned professor knows you and can vouch for your potential in these areas, the recommendation will be beneficial. Recommendations are not focused on what courses the professor teaches. A good recommendation can even come from a non-CS professor (but preferably in a related field like EE) whom you have worked with and knows you personally.